# Why am I getting a segmentation fault at this while loop?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Whenever I execute this program, a segmentation fault is thrown. The program is simple: count the number of vowels in a given string. This is the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

int vowelC(char *in, int c){
  //Declarations
  int i; //Dummy index
  char a; //Temp variable

  //Validate input
  if(!in || c == 0) return 1;

  //Main execution

  //Convert to all lower case
  while(in[i] != '\0'){
       a=in[i];
       if('A' <= a && a <= 'Z')
              a-= ('A' - 'a');
       in[i] = a;
       i++;
  }

  //Count the number of vowels
  while(!in[i]){
             if(in[i] == 'a' || in[i] == 'e' || in[i] == 'i' || in[i] == 'o' || in[i] == 'u')
                     c++;
  }
  return 0;                     
 }

void printUsage(void){
   printf("\n\nThis program will count the number of vowels from an entered character string.\n\t[-c <count>] [-h help]\n\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  //Declarations
  int i; //Dummy index
  int j; //Dummy index
  int count = 0;
  int err;
  int strsize = 0;

  //Is there at least some user input?
  if(argc == 1){
        printUsage();
        return 1;
}

//Determine string size if there is more than two user arguments
for(i=2; i<argc; i++){
         strsize += strlen(argv[i]);
         if (argc > i+1)
            strsize++;
}

//Declare an array of appropriate length to hold the entered strings
char *in = (char *)malloc(strsize);

//Validate input
for(i=1; i<=(argc-2); i++){

         //Determine if the user requested usage
         if(strcmp("-h", argv[i])==0){
                         printUsage();
                         return 1;
         }

         else if(strcmp("-c", argv[i])==0){
                         //There must be at least one argument after a call 
                         if((i+1) == argc){
                                  printUsage();
                                  return 1;
                         }
                         38
                         //Run another loop to retrieve string inputs
                         for(i=2; i<argc; i++){
                                  for(j=0; j != '\0'; j++){//Determine if a sting is really a string
                                           if(isalpha(argv[i][j])){
                                                                   printUsage();
                                                                   return 1;
                                           }
                          }
                          strcat(in, argv[i]);
                          if(argc > (i+1))
                          strcat(in, " ");
                          }

         }

         else{//Unknown input
                        printUsage();
                        return -1;
         }

//For bracket
}

err = vowelC(in, count);
assert(!err);
printf("\n\nThe number of vowels counted is %d.\n\nPlease press enter to exit...", count);
getchar();
return 0;
//Main Bracket    
}
```

GDB reports the segmentation fault occurs at `while(in[i] != '\0')`. However, the reason eludes me. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: If the code would have been compiled with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) the compiler would have warned about *`i` possibly being used uninitialsed*.

Comment: This is *clearly* a student's question, and I daresay he has found this particular mistake highly educational. He's experienced an error that is a consequence of the real problem, he's learnt about segfaults, he's learnt about how arrays are stored, about the importance of initialising variables, about the perils of compiling without warnings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int i; //Dummy index
```

has not been initialized. `i` has storage class auto which means it will not be initialized to a default value and hence can contain any junk value. The values of uninitialized auto variables are undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone has identified the problem but no-one has answered the question, so I will put it together for you: the segfault occurs because your process has attempted to access memory it doesn't own, which has occurred because you haven't initialised the value of `i`.

Arrays are handled, broadly speaking, as contiguous memory. You can think of array element syntax as a kind of function that typecasts and returns the contents of memory at an address calculated from the size of the element type and the index parameter. In your case the type is char, and sizeof(char) returns 1, so `in[i]` is stored at the address of `in[0]` plus `i`.

A crazy value in your index has caused the array element syntax to reference memory out of range resulting in a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

What is `i` - it is not zero

```
while(in[i] != '\0'){
```

Comment: You've got to be kidding me, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: no problem. I wish I could I was not guilty of such things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
while(in[i] != '\0')
```

but you haven't initialize 'i'

**so initialize 'i' with 0**

Answer (score 0):

In line 'while(in[i] != '\0')'-The value of 'i' is not initialized.Please make sure you initialize any variables before you use them in your code.Its a best practice.I have seen whole functionality broken due to this fault.